# Repositioning a label with mouseevents to anywhere on the screen

Tags: c++, qt, mouseevent

I've created a label and used setPixmap to attach a .png image to the label. I've also setWindowFlags to disable the title bar and create a frameless window. Because I've disabled those, it also disables the ability to drag anything around, so I want to create mouseevents (unless there's a better method) to position my label anywhere on the screen exactly like dragging the frame of a window. How would I do that? An example and brief explanation would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

reimplement the `QMouseEvent`s you need .... like

```
void MyLabel::mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent* e)
{
    m_moveDatWidget = true;
    // so when the mousebutton got pressed, you set something to
    // tell your code to move the widget ... consider maybe you
    // want to move it only on right button pressed ...
}

void MyLabel::mouseReleaseEvent(QMouseEvent* e)
{
    m_moveDatWidget = false;
    // after releasing do not forget to reset the movement variable
}

void MyLabel::mouseMoveEvent(QMouseEvent* e)
{
    // when in 'moving state' ...
    if (m_moveDatWidget)
    {
        // move your widget around using QWidget::move(qreal,qreal)
    }
}
```

this is only a really basic implementation but it should do well if you calculate the desired movement correct :)

Answer (score 0):

I would implement the label dragging by mouse in the following way:

```
class Label : public QLabel
{
public:
    // Implement the constructor(s)

protected:
    void Label::mouseMoveEvent(QMouseEvent* event)
    {
        if (!m_offset.isNull()) {
            move(event->globalPos() - m_offset);
        }

        QLabel::mouseMoveEvent(event);
    }

    void Label::mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent* event)
    {
        // Get the mouse offset in the label's coordinates system.
        m_offset = event->globalPos() - pos();
        QLabel::mousePressEvent(event);
    }

    void Notifier::mouseReleaseEvent(QMouseEvent* event)
    {
        m_offset = QPoint();
        QLabel::mouseReleaseEvent(event);
    }

private:
    // The mouse pointer offset from the top left corner of the label.
    QPoint m_offset;
};
```